# How to login when you have a default page setup with panels?

Tags: panels, users

I have been messing with panels.  I set a default layout page that basically has no content and is set for all the pages at the moment.  I logged out like a dummy and now when I go to website/user/login it gives me a blank page.  Is there another way I can login?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have access to drush, you can generate a one time login link use `drush uli`. Other than that, I'm not sure other than manually restoring to a back-up.

Comment: Bummer! You can also try to manually edit/remove the panel from your database, should be in the table page_manager_panels

Comment: try www.example.com/user

Answer (score 0):

> If you have access to drush, you can generate a one time login link use drush >    uli. Other than that, I'm not sure other than manually restoring to a back-up - lukedekker

Awesome!  That worked.  I was trying something else the other day with drush that wasn't producing results.